# Is there a way to see if my model is linked to the correct table?

Tags: cakephp

I'm trying to follow table and class name conventions, but I am not sure if CakePHP is linked with the correct table. For example, `posts_tags` table should be with the class name `PostTag`. Is there a function I can use to check this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, `posts_tags` would be associated with a model `PostsTag` (notice the pluralized Posts).

Second, the table it's using is available in `Model->table`, which is set in `__construct()`.